# Django: How to update an Integerfield and decrement its value

Tags: django, django-models

This seemingly innocuous problem has turned out to be quite difficult to find any information on. I just want to decrement the value of an Integerfield column by 1 in my database, by calling a function.

**views.py function call**

```
StudentProfile.objects.add_lesson(student_id)
```

**managers.py**

```
class StudentQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def add_lesson(self, sid):          
        self.filter(student_id=sid).update(remaining_lessons=remaining - 1)

class StudentProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def add_lesson(self, sid):
        self.get_queryset().add_lesson(sid)
```

**Full StudentProfile model**

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(
        User, related_name='student', primary_key=True, parent_link=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    portrait = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='studentphotos', verbose_name=_('Student Photo'))
    about_me = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("About Me"))
    spoken_languages = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    teacher_default = models.OneToOneField(
        'teachers.TeacherProfile', related_name='teacher_default', parent_link=True, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    membership_start = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Membership Start Date", default=now, editable=False)
    membership_end = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Membership End Date", default=now, editable=False)
    remaining_lessons = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name="Membership remaining lessons", default=0)

    objects = StudentProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return User.objects.get_student_name(self.student_id)
```

I know this is totally wrong, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the F expression, and I have no clue why, but it was decrementing by 3 instead of by 1.  Maybe Django runs that code 3 times when it is called in the view. 
I found a solution that accomplishes this without a function, in the view, it does exactly what I expect, a decrement of 1:

```
student_id = request.user.id
student_queryset = StudentProfile.objects.get(student_id=student_id)
student_queryset.remaining_lessons = student_queryset.remaining_lessons - 1
student_queryset.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your current setup and be able to `add_lesson()` to decrement "remaining_lessons", the smallest change you can do to achieve it is by using F() expression:

```
from django.db.models import F

class StudentQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def add_lesson(self, sid):
        self.filter(student_id=sid).update(remaining_lessons=F('remaining_lessons') - 1)
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/

Although I personally think that if your goal is only to have a method that decrement "remaining_lessons" by 1, you should probably just make it a model method. Like this:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    # ... your model field ...

    def add_lesson(self):
        self.remaining_lesson -= 1
        self.save()

# and in your Views.py
StudentProfile.objects.get(student_id=sid).add_lesson()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Django provides [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) for exactly the kind of task you have. It makes  the update relative to the original field value in the database.

You would need to change your **managers.py** as follows (plus the `return` statements :) )

```
from django.db.models import F

class StudentQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def add_lesson(self, sid):
        return self.filter(student_id=sid).update(remaining_lessons=F('remaining_lessons')-1)


class StudentProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def add_lesson(self, sid):
        return self.get_queryset().add_lesson(sid)
```

You could go even further, and for the sake of DRY approach, use [`QuerySet.as_manager()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods) to create an instance of Manager with a copy of a custom QuerySet’s methods instead of repeating the method twice in your custom Manager and QuerySet. E.g.:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = StudentQuerySet().as_manager()
```

Hope it helps!